# how create a service for installed STUNNEL on CentOS 5.10

Tags: linux, service, centos, startup, stunnel

i have installed stunnel in my centos machine like below :

`yum install stunnel -y`

```
openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 1095
cat privkey.pem cacert.pem >> /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
chmod 600 /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
chown nobody.nobody /var/run/stunnel
```

`nano -K /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf`

```
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
chroot = /var/run/stunnel/
pid = /stunnel.pid
setuid = nobody
setgid = nobody
output = stunnel.log

[squid]
# Ensure the ‘connect’ line matches your squid port. Default is 3128
accept = 8088
connect = 127.0.0.1:1945
```

---

my problem is after stunnel installation **there is no** **service** for installed stunnel.
so i wrote this :

---

`nano -K /etc/init.d/stunnel`

```
#!/bin/bash
#       /etc/rc.d/init.d/stunnel
#
# Starts the stunnel daemon
#
# chkconfig: 345 70 30
# description: Stunnel Server is a ...
# processname: stunnel
# config: /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

test -x /usr/sbin/stunnel || exit 0
RETVAL=0
#
#       See how we were called.
#
prog="stunnel"
start() {
    # Check if stunnel is already running
    if [ ! -f /var/lock/subsys/stunnel ]; 
    then
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    daemon /usr/sbin/stunnel
    RETVAL=$?
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/stunnel
    echo
    fi
    return $RETVAL
}
stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc /usr/sbin/stunnel
    RETVAL=$?
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/stunnel
    echo
    return $RETVAL
}
restart() {
    stop
    start
}
reload() {
    restart
}
status() {
    status /usr/sbin/stunnel
}
case "$1" in
start)
    start
    ;;
stop)
    stop
    ;;
reload|restart)
    restart
    ;;
status)
    status
    ;;
*)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|status}"
    exit 1
esac
exit $?
exit $RETVAL
```

`chmod +x /etc/init.d/stunnel`

`chkconfig --add stunnel`

---

the start command for the written service works fine : **service stunnel start** : **OK**.

but i have error during stop command : **service stunnel stop**  : **FAILED**

and i have error during status command : **service stunnel status** :
**/sbin/service: line 66:  7456 Segmentation fault      env -i LANG="$LANG" PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ${OPTIONS}**

what did i do wrong and how can i fix the problem?
is there a better way for getting that service?

thanks in advance

Comment: here is my stunnel version : stunnel.i386    4.15-2.el5.1    installed

Comment: You have two exit lines at the bottom of that script. That can't possibly work the way you want. Figure out which one of those you want and fix that and see if that helps the `stop` case. What do you get if you run `sh -x /sbin/service stunnel status` (it will likely be a lot of output)?

Comment: dear @Etan Reisner : really really thanks for the attention. finally i found my goal file and put it as my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is what you need :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script to run stunnel in daemon mode at boot time.
#
# Check http://www.gaztronics.net/ for the
# most up-to-date version of this script.
#
# This script is realeased under the terms of the GPL.
# You can source a copy at:
# http://www.fsf.org/copyleft/copyleft.html
#
# Please feel free to modify the script to suite your own needs.
# I always welcome email feedback with suggestions for improvements.
# Please do not email for general support. I do not have time to answer
# personal help requests.

# Author: Gary Myers MIIE MBCS
# email: http://www.gaztronics.net/webform/
# Revision 1.0 - 4th March 2005

#====================================================================
# Run level information:
#
# chkconfig: 2345 99 99
# description: Secure Tunnel
# processname: stunnel
#
# Run "/sbin/chkconfig --add stunnel" to add the Run levels.
# This will setup the symlinks and set the process to run at boot.
#====================================================================

#====================================================================
# Paths and variables and system checks.

# Source function library (It's a Red Hat thing!)
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

# Check that networking is up.
#
[ ${NETWORKING} ="yes" ] || exit 0

# Path to the executable.
#
SEXE=`which stunnel`

# Path to the configuration file.
#
CONF=/etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf

# Check the configuration file exists.
#
if [ ! -f $CONF ] ; then
  echo "The configuration file cannot be found!"
exit 0
fi

CHROOT=`grep '^chroot' /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf | head -n 1 | sed 's/ //g' | awk -F= '{ print $2 }'`
PIDFILE=`grep '^pid' /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf | head -n 1 | sed 's/ //g' | awk -F= '{ print $2 }'`
if [ -n "$CHROOT" ]; then
    PIDFILE=$CHROOT/$PIDFILE
fi

# Path to the lock file.
#
LOCK_FILE=/var/lock/subsys/stunnel

#====================================================================

#====================================================================
# Run controls:

prog=$"stunnel"

RETVAL=0

# Start stunnel as daemon.
#
start() {
  if [ -f $LOCK_FILE ]; then
    echo "stunnel is already running!"
    exit 0
  else
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    $SEXE $CONF
  fi

  RETVAL=$?
  [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && success
  echo
  [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $LOCK_FILE
  return $RETVAL
}


# Stop stunnel.
#
stop() {
  if [ ! -f $LOCK_FILE ]; then
    echo "stunnel is not running!"
    exit 0

  else

    echo -n $"Shutting down $prog: "
    killproc -p $PIDFILE stunnel
    RETVAL=$?
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]
     rm -f $LOCK_FILE
    echo
    return $RETVAL

  fi
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
   start)
  start
  ;;
   stop)
  stop
  ;;
   restart)
  stop
  start
  ;;
   condrestart)
  if [ -f $LOCK_FILE ]; then
     stop
     start
     RETVAL=$?
  fi
  ;;
   status)
  status -p $PIDFILE stunnel
  RETVAL=$?
  ;;
   *)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|condrestart|status}"
    RETVAL=1
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: I ended up downloading the source for my version from http://www.stunnel.org/download/source.html. Then I found the default config and init file in the tools folder.

Comment: This is the way to go, the stunnel source has a bunch of tools!